# std::locale has no equivalent to lconv::p_cs_precedes?

Tags: c++, c, locale

I notice that there are mappings in std::locale for most of the localeconv() lconv:: fields.  For example:

```
char *decimal_point;        // LC_NUMERIC, std::numpunct::decimal_point()
char *thousands_sep;        // LC_NUMERIC, std::numpunct::thousands_sep()
char *grouping;             // LC_NUMERIC, std::numpunct::grouping()

char *int_curr_symbol;      // LC_MONETARY, std::moneypunct<,true>::curr_symbol()
char *currency_symbol;      // LC_MONETARY, std::moneypunct::curr_symbol()
char *mon_decimal_point;    // LC_MONETARY, std::moneypunct::decimal_point()
char *mon_thousands_sep;    // LC_MONETARY, std::moneypunct::thousands_sep()
char *mon_grouping;         // LC_MONETARY, std::moneypunct::grouping()
char *positive_sign;        // LC_MONETARY, std::moneypunct::positive_sign()
char *negative_sign;        // LC_MONETARY, std::moneypunct::negative_sign()
char int_frac_digits;       // LC_MONETARY, std::moneypunct<,true>::curr_symbol()
char frac_digits;           // LC_MONETARY, std::moneypunct::frac_digits()
```

However, some of the fields, I see no C++ mechanism for getting the same information from the locale, as we can get in C.  In particular, I don't see a way of getting at equivalents to the following members:

```
char p_cs_precedes;         // LC_MONETARY, 1 if currency_symbol is placed before non-negative monetary value, 0 if after 
char p_sep_by_space;        // LC_MONETARY, indicates the separation of currency_symbol, positive_sign, and the non-negative monetary value 
char n_cs_precedes;         // LC_MONETARY, 1 if currency_symbol is placed before negative value, 0 if after 
char n_sep_by_space;        // LC_MONETARY, indicates the separation of currency_symbol, negative_sign, and the negative monetary value
char p_sign_posn;           // LC_MONETARY, indicates the position of positive_sign in a non-negative monetary value 
char n_sign_posn;           // LC_MONETARY, Value indicating the position of the negative_sign for a negative formatted monetary quantity.
```

I am curious why these were left out of the C++ interface, since I'd imagine a use case for an equivalent interface to make C to C++ porting easier (for example, to make use of per-thread locales, which can't be portably done in C, but can be in C++).

Answer (score 1):

I missed the moneypunct::pos_pattern() and ::neg_pattern() functions when I was looking through the documentation.  These encode fields like p_cs_precedes=1 by returning something like:

```
{..., symbol, ..., value, ...}
```